# Passing HashMap to bean available in Jar in Camel

Tags: hashmap, apache-camel

I have situation as described below.

I have a client API which has to be integrated to a camel application.

API requires a `HashMap` as an input.It doesnt returs any value.

Map object will be constructed in the camel application

Map set constructed in sampleBean will have to be passed to `BeanInJar.someMethod()`

Below is route

-->MAp will be constructed here and set in `exchange.setProperties()`

method in bean available in jar

```
public void someMetod(Map<String,Object){

    //Some Code goes here

  }
```

Thanks.

Regards
Senthil Kumar Sekar

Comment: Your problem looks clear, but what are you asking? Do you need to define the route? Or to construct the HashMap?

Comment: I want to pass the Map object constructed in the camel project to the method someMethod(Map<String,Object>) which is available in the jar.I will invoke the method in the route.Now how do i pass the hashmap to someMethod()

Comment: You could write a bean which has a method which creates the Map and puts it on the exchange body... `exchange.getIn().setBoday(new HashMap<...>)`. Is that enough help, or do you need a code example?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bean which puts an empty `Map<...>` on the exchange body:

```
public class CreateEmptyMapBean {

    public void createMapOnExchangeBody(Exchange exchange) {
        exchange.getIn().setBody(new HashMap<String, Object));
    }
}
```

Now just call this bean directly before `BeanInJar.someMethod()`.

Comment: Basically i want to make my bean available in the jar independent of Camel stuffs.so that i can use the api(jar) whichever application i want.IS this possible?I understand that we can pass the params with Camel's Exchange OBject.IS it possible that i pass the Properties/Headers in Camel Exchange via camel routes.This will make by bean's method's parameter to be Map(Java Objects) which will independent of camel imports

Comment: Is it possible to pass the Camel's properties/Headers through EL or something in Camel route defined in Spring-DSL

Comment: I can inject my bean(available in Jar) to the bean available in camel project and there i can call the sampleMethod which is present in the jar.But tomorrow if i want to remove the api from the camel application, i need to remove the above unwanted code manually.I need to use the API(JAR) as plugggable/loosely coupled

Comment: Yes you can pass an object (such as your map) as an exchange property. The bean can access this property via `Exchange` objcet or as a method parameter annotated like this: `@Property("myMap") Map<String, Object> theMap`

Comment: Here my bean method's parameter will depend on Camel dependencies(imports) which i want to ignore.
Integrating my api's should be loosely coupled.Later stage i can switch to different api which should be done easilyThats the idea....